# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function C++ DLL clang

Tags: c++, dll

estoy creando un logger y me gustaria que fuese un DLL, para esto creo una clase `Logger` la cual es un singleton por lo tanto solo existe una instancia. La clase se ve asi

```cpp
// logger.hpp
#pragma once

#include "defines.hpp"

#include <iostream>

enum logLevel {
    FATAL_LOG_LEVEL   = 0,
    ERROR_LOG_LEVEL   = 1,
    WARNING_LOG_LEVEL = 2,
    INFO_LOG_LEVEL    = 3,
    TRACE_LOG_LEVEL   = 4,
    DEBUG_LOG_LEVEL   = 5
};

/**
 * @class Logger
 * @brief The Logger class provides logging functionality for the application.
 *        It allows logging messages of different severity levels to various output destinations.
 *        This class follows the Singleton pattern to ensure only one instance exists.
 */

class ENGINE_API Logger {
    protected:
        Logger () = default;
        ~Logger() = default;

        static Logger* unique_instance; // Singleton instance of the Logger class
    
    public:
        /*
         * @brief Initializes the Logger instance.
         * @param filepath to the logfile where the log are write.
         */
        void initilize (string filepath);
        
        /**
         * @brief Shuts down the Logger instance.
         */
        void shutdown ();

        /**
         * @brief Retrieves the unique instance of the Logger class.
         * @return A pointer to the single Logger instance.
         */
        static Logger* get_unique_instance ();

       /**
         * @brief Logs a message at the FATAL level.
         * @param message The log message to be logged.
         * @param args Additional arguments to be formatted into the message (variadic).
         */
        template<typename ...Args>
        static void fatal (string message, Args... args);

        /**
         * @brief Logs a message at the ERROR level.
         * @param message The log message to be logged.
         * @param args Additional arguments to be formatted into the message (variadic).
         */
        template<typename ...Args>
        static void error (string message, Args... args);

        /**
         * @brief Logs a message at the WARNING level.
         * @param message The log message to be logged.
         * @param args Additional arguments to be formatted into the message (variadic).
         */
        template<typename ...Args>
        static void warning (string message, Args... args);

        /**
         * @brief Logs a message at the INFO level.
         * @param message The log message to be logged.
         * @param args Additional arguments to be formatted into the message (variadic).
         */
        template<typename ...Args>
        static void info  (string message, Args... args);

        /**
         * @brief Logs a message at the TRACE level.
         * @param message The log message to be logged.
         * @param args Additional arguments to be formatted into the message (variadic).
         */
        template<typename ...Args>
        static void trace (string message, Args... args);

        /**
         * @brief Logs a message at the DEBUG level.
         * @param message The log message to be logged.
         * @param args Additional arguments to be formatted into the message (variadic).
         */
        template<typename ...Args>
        static void debug (string message, Args... args);

    private:
        /**
         * @brief Logs a message at the specified log level.
         * @param level The severity level of the log message.
         * @param message The log message to be logged.
         * @param args Additional arguments to be formatted into the message (variadic).
         */
        template<typename ...Args>
        void log_message (logLevel level, string message, Args... args);
};
```

Y la logica de cada funcion la tengo en mi archivo `.ccp`

```
#include "logger.hpp"

Logger* Logger::unique_instance = nullptr;

// Open and close the log file
// the log file depends of the actual date and hours
Logger* Logger::get_unique_instance () {
    if (unique_instance == nullptr) {
        unique_instance = new Logger();
    }

    return unique_instance;
}

template<typename ...Args>
void Logger::log_message (logLevel level, string message, Args... args) {
    // assing the basic caracteristic to the output
    string level_strings[]      = {"[FATAL]",  "[ERROR]",  "[WARNING]", "[INFO]",   "[TRACE]",  "[DEBUG]"}; 
    string level_colors_codes[] = {"\033[31m", "\033[35m", "\033[33m",  "\033[36m", "\033[32m", "\033[37m",};
    string resert_color_code    = "\033[0m";

    // Format the message using std::format (c++20)
    string output_message = level_colors_codes[level] 
                          + level_strings[level] 
                          + ": " 
                          + std::format(message, args...)
                          + resert_color_code;

    // write in console.
    std::cout << output_message << std::endl;
}

template <typename... Args>
void Logger::fatal(string message, Args... args) {
    Logger::get_unique_instance()->log_message(FATAL_LOG_LEVEL, args...);
}

template<typename ...Args>
void Logger::error (string message, Args...) {}

template<typename ...Args>
void Logger::warning (string message, Args...) {}

template<typename ...Args>
void Logger::info (string message, Args...) {}

template<typename ...Args>
void Logger::trace (string message, Args...) {}

template<typename ...Args>
void Logger::debug (string message, Args...) {}
```

Para exportar los dll tengo un archivo `defines.hpp`

```cpp
// Platform detection
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) 
#define KPLATFORM_WINDOWS 1
#ifndef _WIN64
#error "64-bit is required on Windows!"
#endif
#elif defined(__linux__) || defined(__gnu_linux__)
// Linux OS
#define KPLATFORM_LINUX 1
#if defined(__ANDROID__)
#define KPLATFORM_ANDROID 1
#endif
#elif defined(__unix__)
// Catch anything not caught by the above.
#define KPLATFORM_UNIX 1
#elif defined(_POSIX_VERSION)
// Posix
#define KPLATFORM_POSIX 1
#elif __APPLE__
// Apple platforms
#define KPLATFORM_APPLE 1
#include <TargetConditionals.h>
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
// iOS Simulator
#define KPLATFORM_IOS 1
#define KPLATFORM_IOS_SIMULATOR 1
#elif TARGET_OS_IPHONE
#define KPLATFORM_IOS 1
// iOS device
#elif TARGET_OS_MAC
// Other kinds of Mac OS
#else
#error "Unknown Apple platform"
#endif
#else
#error "Unknown platform!"
#endif

#ifdef KEXPORT
// Exports
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define ENGINE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define ENGINE_API __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif
#else
// Imports
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define ENGINE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#define ENGINE_API
#endif
#endif
```

Pero cuando compilo me manda el siguiente error:

```
clang++  C:\Users\Jose\Documents\projectos\vulkan\engine\src\core\logger.cpp C:\Users\Jose\Documents\projectos\vulkan\engine\src\plataform\filesystem.cpp C:\Users\Jose\Documents\projectos\vulkan\testbed\src\main.cpp -g -shared -Wvarargs -Wall -Werror -o ../bin/engine.dll -D_DEBUG -DKEXPORT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -Isrc -ID:\VulkanSDK\1.3.250.1/Include -luser32 -lvulkan-1 -LD:\VulkanSDK\1.3.250.1/Lib

filesystem-177c61.o : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function "public: void __cdecl std::allocator<char>::deallocate(char * const,unsigned __int64)" (?deallocate@?$allocator@D@std@@QEAAXQEAD_K@Z)
..\bin\engine.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1120 (use -v to see invocation)
Error:1120
```

Como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: `_CrtDbgReport` es una función que MSVC usa en compilaciones debug, o estás mezclando compilación release y debug o bien has cambiado algo de tu compilación debug que hace que dejes de enlazar con las librerías debug de MSVC.